# Cannot permanently save deltalake table with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, delta-lake

I've been struggling with this problem for a while

I'm processing a bunch of csv files in batches, saving as tables specifically setting the property **Temporary** to **False** and still when running a new session of pyspark I cannot find the database, or the table.

I start my pyspark session here with:

```
builder = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("my-app-name")
           .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
           .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
           .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "3000s")
           .config("spark.network.timeout", "3600s")
           .config("spark.driver.memory", "30g"))

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

Here's my simplified code:

```
for i in tqdm(range(0, len(data_files), batch_size)):
    df = read_csvs(spark, data_files[i:i + batch_size])
    ... processing stuf ....
    df.write.options(temporary="false").format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable(f"{config_base['database']}.{config_base['table']}")  # I've tried also save(path)

print(spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show())
print(spark.sql(f"SHOW TABLES FROM {config_base['database']}").show())
```

And this two last lines shows me that both the database and the table were created without issues:

| namespace |
| --- |
| my_database |
| default |

| namespace | tableName | isTemporary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my_database | my_table | false |

But, when I start a pyspark session with `pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.0.0 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" --conf "spark.driver.memory=30g" --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=0"`:

and ask for the databases, all I have is:

| namespace |
| --- |
| default |

Why is my database no visible? I can see that the files still in the spark-warehouse

Thanks!

Edit: I'm working locally